# Inconsistent query speed between LINQ and (sometimes) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, linq, stored-procedures

I have a strange inconsistenty in query speed with linq to sql functions. I have a function which I call from an MVC application. This is invariably extremely slow, in the order of 7 seconds. When I call the same function from SQL management studio, it is sometimes slow, and sometimes fast (a fraction of a second). I'm not sure when it becomes slow, and when it becomes fast exactly, but I have found one cycle (apart from the MVC application always being slow) that gives consistent results.

- The query runs in the application. This is slow.
- I try the query exactly as LINQ performs it. This is in the form `sp_execute N' select [some] [select] [clauses] from functionname(@p0)', 'declare @p0 decimal(9,0)', @p0=123456789`. This is also slow, on a first run, and on consecutive runs.
- I try the query "unwrapped" in the form `select [some] [select] [clauses] from functionname(123456789)`. This is still slow, also on consecutive runs.
- I re-define the function with alter function [...].
- running the original sp_execute query is still slow, also on censecutive runs.
- running the unwrapped function is fast. Really fast.
- running the original sp_execute query is now really fast too. Also with different @p0 parameters.
- the query runs in the application. we're back to being slow.

I'm completely and utterly puzzeled as to why this happens, and how I can remedy it. It feels like it has something to do with cached execution plans or something of the kind, but I don't know enough about that to know exactly what is going on - or how to remedy it. Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: are all possible fields indexed? do you run index rebuild and statistics update jobs at night?

Comment: If it's slow on consecutive runs, it's probably not due to compiling and cached excecution plans.

Comment: the hit tables are indexed fairly well, I see no apparent missing indexes. I refreshed all statistics prior to running these tests. If the indexing needs work, would that explain the consistent either very quick (fraction of a second), or (for the identical query) 7 to 11 seconds? If it were an indexing problem I would have at least expected consistent bad performance. I don't know enough about statistics to know if this could be caused by "bad" statistics, but I thought repeated runs with different parameters should rule that out.

Comment: "If the indexing needs work, would that explain the consistent either very quick (fraction of a second), or (for the identical query) 7 to 11 seconds?" -- Possibly.  The data being queried may be mostly cached in some cases, and in others it may have to read everything from disk.  The former cases might be considerably faster than the latter cases simply because you are avoiding a lot of I/O overhead.

Comment: what exactly you did with function when you said "I re-define the function with alter function [...]." did you mean that your recreate the function as it is w/o changing anything in definition or parameters? or you did change something in it? can you post the body of the function and what is the parameter Datatype. What is the Column DataType against which this value is being used inside function.

Comment: Hi Anup, I did the latter, recreate the function while changing nothing in the definition

Comment: ok. can you tell more about what is in function, how many tables are there and what logic is implemented (basically function body, table definitions etc..), because you see if the query inside the function is not written properly then no matter what optimization you to in wrapper will not work long. by looking at table definition we will come to know indexes/Column Null-Ability, Cardinality etc... I would  divide the problem in two parts. first the function itself should give consistent execution plan and execution time from SSMS and then will see Application side.

Comment: The function itself consists 6 tables, with inner and outer joins,  an outer apply to another function. I've got the function body inlined in an SQL string now (yuk), which works performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like Parameter Sniffing:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/
http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx

The articles describe it very well, but in a nutshell: the engine makes some assumptions about optimizing a query based on the parameters that are passed in, which causes slower-than-optimal performance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be explained by issue of *[parameter sniffing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/)* and, also, different *[execution settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180202.aspx)* between you MVC application and SQL Management studio. The difference can be dramatic.

Additional information according to execution settings can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Among this, there's some other tips in the article http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

And, sure, for check correctness, need to clean cashed planes:
[DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx); [DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the query is taking time in first time execution on SQL management studio  and taking less time subsequently is due to the reason that when the query gets executed, the data gets stored in SQL server cache.
And when the same query is executed again, then data is fetched from Cache.

To see the exact time taken by query, you need to clear the cache before running the query
and that can be done by

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS

Comment: How about the still slow consecutive runs?